# Locking causes database actions to be too slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, msdtc

```
lock (_connectionLock) {
    if (conn == null) {
        conn = GetOpenConnection(connectionString);
    } 

    try {
        PerformDbAction(conn);
    } finally {
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I have run into a problem where multithreading can cause issues with null connections as they can be opened and closed by several threads running at once. I tried to solve the issue by locking the process (above, code simplified for clarity) but have found that this seriously slows down the performance.

I tried to get around this problem by using two separate locks for the creation/disposal of database connections and to perform database action outside of locking:

```
lock (_connectionLock) {
    if (conn == null) {
        conn = GetOpenConnection(connectionString);
    } 
}

try {
    PerformDbAction(conn);
} finally {
    lock(_connectionLock) 
    conn.Dispose();
}
}
```

Only I realized that the above doesn't work as another thread may try to perform a database action with a connection that has already been disposed by another thread.

Could anyone suggest an alternative or solution where I can safely lock access to the database connection strings without slowing everything down so much?

**EDIT:** Sorry for not including this previously, but the reason I am not just creating new connections and disposing of them immediately is that I am trying to avoid unwanted MSDTC escalation. In using GetOpenConnection I am reusing an existing connection as this is one of the things that triggers MSDTC escalation.

I have managed to avoid the escalation with the top code example, but it performs way too slow.

Comment: Are you using only 1 connection? Using multiple ones at the same time, one per thread, is both safe and fine, although if you deal with the same data, in the end the database engine will handle locks for you.

Comment: Wait, what?

How can you end up with a null connection *string*?  Do you mean a null *connection*?  Thats a different matter.  Can you post the code of the GetOpenConnection() method?

Comment: @Tyler: Just don't do it.  Create a new connection every time and let the database provider do its own pooling.  Don't share anything across threads.

Comment: @SLaks will give that a try. And thanks CAbbott for code format, when I paste in it just ends up all over the place. How did you do it?

Comment: Select the code and press Control-K.

Comment: Also, please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @SLaks: Ugh, yes of course I do :(

Comment: That's the advantage of the diamond.

Comment: @ChrisShain sorry I meant a connection that had already been disposed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply don't have *one* shared connection variable. Instead, each time you need to do something, open a connection, use it, and close it as soon as you can. You don't need to use any locks in your code, and the connection pool will manage the real network connections to the database.

At the moment, you've essentially built a primitive connection pool containing exactly one connection, which means you've got no concurrency at all in the database (well, not per process).

Comment: I did it this way to try and avoid MSDTC issues that have arisen with muliple connections (or the same connection from multiple Linq data contexts, at least). Thanks for answer, will give it a try

Comment: @Tyler: You should give details of those issues then - this almost certainly *isn't* the right way to solve them.

Comment: sorry for not including that in the question Jon. Have you got any suggestions how I could approach this problem and also be able to avoid MSDTC escalation?

Comment: @Tyler: Using the connection pool you should end up reusing the same connection where you can anyway.